# UINavigation Bar Color

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have written the following code to set up the navigation bar and the view of the view controller:

1. Navigation bar at the AppDelegate:

   ```
   var navigationController = UINavigationController()

   navigationController.viewControllers = [mainViewController]
   ```
2. MainViewController A:

   ```
   self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
   let fullScreenRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
   let buttonSize:CGFloat = 60
   let viewLogButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: fullScreenRect.size.height-buttonSize, width:fullScreenRect.size.width, height: buttonSize))
   viewLogButton.setTitle("View Log", for: UIControlState.normal)
   viewLogButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
   viewLogButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: .highlighted)
   viewLogButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
   viewLogButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(viewLogButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
   self.view.addSubview(viewLogButton)
   self.webView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y:    UIConstants.NAVIGATION_BAR_HEIGHT+UIConstants.STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT, width: fullScreenRect.size.width, height: fullScreenRect.size.height-buttonSize-UIConstants.NAVIGATION_BAR_HEIGHT-UIConstants.STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT)
   self.view.addSubview(self.webview)
   ```

This resulted in a view with the top navigation bar shows a semi-transparent blue color. 
[image: MainViewController A]

I then do the same in another ViewController B (which is a table view controller):

3. MainViewController B:

   ```
   let tableView = UITableView()
   let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds    
   self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
   let screenWidth = screenSize.width
   let screenHeight = screenSize.height
   tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight)    
   self.view.addSubview(tableView)
   ```

[image: MainViewController B]

I'd like to know why there is semi-transparent navigation bar in MainViewController A but MainViewController B cannot shows that?

How can I make both of them show the same semi-transparent color navigation bar?

Comment: subClass NavigationController & add customize attributes .This will reflect everywhere in app.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to change UINavigationBar all the places Globaly, Call it from `AppDelegate`

```
func setupNaviBarAppearnce() {

    UINavigationBar.appearance().isOpaque = true
    UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = true
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = Theme.AppMainPurpleColor
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName:Typography.navigationTitle!,NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.white]
}
```

NOTE: You need to modify it as per your requirement and UI

Comment: I tried. isTranslucent, barTintColor are not available in iOS10.

Comment: no it is  `@available(iOS 3.0, *)
    open var isTranslucent: Bool // Default is NO on iOS 6 and earlier. Always YES if barStyle is set to UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent`

Comment: for Bar tint color     `@available(iOS 7.0, *)
    open var barTintColor: UIColor? // default is nil` Just Command and click on  `barTintColor`

Comment: did it help ? ,or  you need something more ?

Comment: actually, my question is how come there is a semi-transparent bar at the top for the ViewControllerA and no such color on the ViewController B. I cannot understand which part of my code cause that. 

I cannot use the appearance().isTranslucent in iOS10

Comment: and what if i want to change those text at the top to another color?

Comment: I can only do this

navigationController.navigationBar.isOpaque = true
    navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = /UIColor.blue
    navigationController.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true

Comment: after putting  that function did you try to compile code ? , as i mentioned with this method all over application you can get a same navigation color , and style which is standard